# Python calling the main function

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am kicking myself right now. I managed to create the code I need for an assignment, but then realized I didn't write it in the "main function", and for the life of me I can't seem to fix it. It's the last step I need to submit it, can some one please help?

```
rays_starters = {'DeJesus': ['DH', 6, 299], #First dictionary with original starters
                'Loney': ['1B', 4, 222],
                'Rivera': ['C', 9, 194],
                'Forsythe': ['2B', 5, 304],
                'Souza Jr': ['RF', 2, 229],
                'Longoria': ['3B', 3, 282],
                'Cabrera': ['SS', 7, 214],
                'Kiermaier': ['CF', 1, 240],
                'Guyer': ['LF', 8, 274]}

print ('\n' + 'Ray\'s Starters' + '\n') #Prints the list of the players 
for player in rays_starters:
    print (player + str(rays_starters[player]))

print ('\n' + 'Today\'s lineup' + '\n') #Prints the current lineup in batting order 
for key, value in sorted(rays_starters.items(), key=lambda v: v[1][1]):
    print("Batting {}: {} {}, current avg: {}".format(value[1], value[0], key, value[2]))

rays_replacements = {'Beckham': ['DH', 6, 299], #New dictionary with replacements
                    'Loney': ['1B', 4, 222],
                    'Wilson': ['C', 9, 194],
                    'Forsythe': ['2B', 5, 304],
                    'Souza Jr': ['RF', 2, 229],
                    'Longoria': ['3B', 3, 282],
                     }
```

Comment: Do you need it in a main function for the assignment? It will run just as it is without a `main()`.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked the instructions from the Professor. He wanted in in main. I know the code works, which I am super happy about, but now I don't know how to get it into main() :(

Comment: Thank you Andy! You are my new favorite person today :)

Comment: @LauraJones when you post a question you should include what attempts you have used to try to solve the problem, for example linking to other stackoverflow questions. That may be the reason your question was downvoted.

Comment: I'm new to the site, so my apologies. The only thing I had tried prior to Andy giving me the missing link, was to def main() at the start and main () at the end...I left out the if __name__ == "__main__": before the main()...I also apologize about the formatting errors, I am new to this and not seeing how to post this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you just need to wrap your code in a function named `main`

```
def main():
    # All your code here, with proper indention of 1 additional level
```

Then you need to add this to the end of your file so that when you run `python yourfile.py` it properly executes

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you want to run it directly from a shell you can also add the `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line, then with appropriate permissions you can simply do `$ yourfile.py`